# Batch file: Extract characters from the end of a string in a loop

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I would like to extract characters from the end of a string.

```
    SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion

    SET str=123456789abcdefgh

    FOR /l %%x IN (1, 1, 10) DO (
       ECHO %%x
       SET result=%%str%:~-%%x%
       ECHO "Extracted characters: " !result!
    )

    ENDLOCAL
```

This is my incorrect output:

1
"Extracted characters: " %str:~-1

2
"Extracted characters: " %str:~-2

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: no, `!result!` is the only way it works here (inside a block)

Comment: @Stephan - That is the best way, but not the only way. See [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31910049/1012053)

Comment: Please do not ask the same question twice. I edited out your appended question. It was either that, or have your [later question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/31908092/1012053) deleted.

Answer (score 5):

You shouldn't use 
`SET result=%%str%:~-%%x%`
Instead, 
`SET result=!str:~-%%x!`

Answer (score 0):

I would use delayed expansion as [dark fang has done](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31905962/1012053). But just to show that there is another way, albeit much slower:

```
@echo off
setlocal
SET str=123456789abcdefgh

FOR /l %%x IN (1, 1, 10) DO (
  ECHO %%x
  CALL ECHO %%str:~-%%x%%
)
```

The slowness is not really noticeable with a few iterations, but a loop with thousands of iterations will be noticeably slower.