# Windows batch file:Variables in loop

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I am trying to copy files recursively 
and then rename them according their containg folder name.

I am trying to extract folder name from path.
So far I got this but id does not work:

```
SET "MyPath=C:\MyFolder\"

SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion

FOR /R "%MyPath%" %%F DO (

    ECHO "%%~pF" :: ~pF expands F to a path only

    :: this is in my case a variable (length of a file that comes froma function call)
    SET /a intFileLength=5 


    SET strPathOnly=%%~pF

    SET folderName=!strPathOnly:~-intFileLength!
    ECHO "Extracted folder name: " !folderName!
)

endlocal
```

This is my echo
Extracted folder name: " strPathOnly:~-intFileLength

```
    SET /a intFileLength = 5

    :: The following works
    SET folderName=!strPathOnly:~-5!

    :: This one does not work
    SET folderName=!strPathOnly:~-intFileLength!
```

Comment: This can be done, but.......... just don't. Use something else other than a dos batch file. For copying files, I suggest `robocopy`. You might also look at `forfiles`. But seriously, `robocopy`.

Comment: You can get the parent folder name easily - but your code doesn't show clearly what you are trying to do.  You are somehow using the filesize from what your code shows.

Comment: It's not working because you're using the literal string `intFileLength` instead of the intFileLength variable.

Comment: Also: `::` isn't the official method for adding comments. Use `rem` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Your FOR loop is a mess - a FOR loop cannot work without an IN() clause. I can only guess what your intent is.

Regardless, you cannot do substring operations on FOR variables - you must store the value in an environment variable before you manipulate it. Also, you must transfer the count to a FOR variable so that you can use it as a substring argument within delayed expansion.

```
@echo off
SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion
SET "MyPath=C:\MyFolder\"

FOR /R "%MyPath%" %%F in (*) DO (
  set "str=%%~pF"
  SET /a suffixToExtractLength=5
  for %%N in (!suffixToExtractLength!) do SET "result=!str:~-%%N!"
  ECHO Extracted characters: !result!
)
endlocal
```